# FluentD, how to grep only spcific logs

Tags: fluentd, td-agent

```
2019/08/13 13:13:17 [DEBUG] Hello, world!
2019/08/13 13:13:17 [INFO] Ignore me
2019/08/13 13:13:17 [INFO] SPECIFIC_LOG :{"name": "mark"}
```

I have like above logs, and I need to grep only the logs which contains 'SPECIFIC_LOG' and I want to ignore the others.

I tried to set the config like this,

```
<source>
    @type tail
    path ./sample.log
    tag debug.sample
    <parse>
        @type regexp
        expression /\[\w+\] SPECIFIC_LOG\s:(?<message>.*)$/
    </parse>
</source>

<filter debug.**>
    @type parser
    key_name message
    format json
</filter>
```

And it is working for the matched log with pattern, but for the not matched log, I got warning which says

```
#0 pattern not matched: "2019/08/13 13:13:17 [DEBUG] Hello, world!"
```

How can I grep only the log which is matched the pattern, so that I can resolve the warning?

Answer (score 0):

It is just a warning that pattern did not match and in my opinion, it can be ignored.

To ignore such warnings, you can set `emit_invalid_record_to_error false` option.

```
<filter debug.**>
    @type parser
    key_name message
    format json
    emit_invalid_record_to_error false
</filter>
```

More info on this flag - 
https://docs.fluentd.org/filter/parser#emit_invalid_record_to_error

Earlier versions had `suppress_parse_error_log` flag and now it has been replaced with `emit_invalid_record_to_error`.

**suppress_parse_error_log is missing. What are the alternatives?**

Since v1, `parser` filter doesn't support `suppress_parse_error_log` parameter because parser filter uses @ERROR feature instead of internal logging to rescue invalid records. If you want to simply ignore invalid records, set emit_invalid_record_to_error false.
See also emit_invalid_record_to_error parameter.